# how to calculate weighted transitivity with networkx in Python

Tags: python, networkx, weighted-graph, transitivity

As far as I know, the function in networkx for graph's transitivity is unweighted (shown as follow).

```
networkx.transitivity(G)
```

I have tried it on a weighted graph, but in the results, only edges are considered. Is there any other way in networkx to calculate weighted transitivity?
Besides, I only find the way in [R](https://igraph.org/r/doc/transitivity.html), but I know nothing about R.

Answer (score 1):

As you stated, the `networkx.transitivity` function computes an unweighted transitivity measure for the whole graph. If you're referencing the weighted transitivity option from the R `igraph` [package](https://igraph.org/r/doc/transitivity.html) it doesn't look like networkx directly implements this calculation. However there is a function `networkx.clustering(G, nodes=None, weight=None)` [(docs)](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable//reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.cluster.clustering.html) that calculates a similar metric, but the formula aren't the same.

If you're looking for a python implementation of the formula from the igraph R package, you can also look into the python implementation of igraph which has a graph class with functions that compute local and global weighted transitivity [(docs)](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html)

Comment: I have checked the function `transitivity_avglocal_undirected(self, mode='nan', weights=None)` in `igraph`, and its definition is what exactly `network.average_clustering()` is. But what I want to calculate is **transitivity**, [which are slightly different from average clustering coefficience](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/python-social-network-analysis/clustering-coefficient-ZhNvi).